# How can Make a selection to filter out the duplicates without grouping them? I want them all to display individually?

Tags: sql

I have some data in a database that is sorted into a text column a individual identifier for each text item and a language for each of these text columns.

```
 SELECT Text, Language, COUNT(*)
 FROM TableA
 WHERE Language = 'English'
 GROUP BY Text, Language 
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This Query gives me a list of the data I need however I have 2 issues, It is grouped up so the results display as:

```
|    Text    | Language | Amount Counted  |
|------------|----------|-----------------|
| Hello Text | English  |               5 |
```

The issue is I can sort based on the text to make a count however I cannot figure out how to add the unique identifier in there and list these out as one big list? For example The text 'Hello' could be in the list 5 Times and I would get this listed as above. However Each version of hello Will have a Different ID Value Perhaps The first version of Hello is (ID 232) and the Second is (ID 546) how can I add in the ID value which is in the same table and just list all the duplicated with their ID values?

So I would get As a example:

```
|      Text      | Language | ID   |
|----------------|----------|------|
| Hello Text     | English  |  232 |
| Hello Text     | English  |  546 |
| Hello Text     | English  |  643 |
| Hello Text     | English  |  745 |
| Hello Text     | English  | 1353 |
| Other Text     | English  |  343 |
| Other Text     | English  |  433 |
| Different Text | English  |  433 |
| Different Text | English  |  437 |
| Different Text | English  |  563 |
| Different Text | English  |  898 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want a window function?

```
SELECT text, language, id
FROM (SELECT a.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Text) as cnt
      FROM TableA a
      WHERE Language = 'English'
     ) a
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: This is absolutely what I was looking for, I have never heard of a window function? I will have to do some research into those, I am still fairly new to Sql at the moment, Is there a way to order based of the ID? Order By seems to crop up some errors?